# Could not find method exception when clicking a binded button in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a simple button made in my android application.

In xml, it looks like this:

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_column="9"
                android:onClick="calculate"/>
```

And also I have a corresponding method in my `MainActivity` class. Showing the whole class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void testClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GerminativeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void calculate(View v) {
        System.out.print("||||||||||| HERE");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now when I click that button on my emulated Nexus 5 device, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calculate(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button'
```

What could be the issue here? I have never had such an issue before when developing on android. Making a new button and a new method that the button is linked to will throw the same error.

Can edit my post and provide the full stacktrace if needed.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but is the Button xml in the activity_main.xml?

Comment: "Can edit my post and provide the full stacktrace if needed." it may not make a difference here but it is always a good idea to post the full stacktrace. Apart from what was asked by @BinaryJudy I would suggest cleaning and rebuilding the project. And no, it's not a stupid question, Judy, it happens

Comment: Yes, the button xml is in the activity main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is affecting Android 5.0 when applying the android:theme attribute.

Ahmeds, answer is right, with addition that in your case, click listener must be set in the classic java way. I have found that [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62795)

Comment: But I don't think I have applied any custom themes in my application. I only did this:` android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

Comment: ti doesn't have to be custom theme.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are referencing to the the XML which has this button.

i.e.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and that R.layout.activity_main has the your button in it. If not this is not going to work. However you can try the following as well,

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        calculate(v);
    }
});
```

It doesnt have any difference then what you are trying to do. If you define your clicklistener in XML Android takes care of creating `OnClickListener` for you. However you can do the same by defining one in the code yourself.

Comment: The first part is all set, only thing is that the buttons I really have also reference some gradients from other xml files in drawable. But it should not matter as a vanilla button with no bling on it throws the same error. I could do the manual listener indeed but what would cause  this error anyways.

Comment: Milos answer is also correct. Please take a look the link,
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62795

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seems I had this in my main xml: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`. Removing it removed the error. So it appears I can not customize my theme without breaking the whole application?

Comment: Yeah this sometimes happens too. But this might have possible solutions to it.